# Как создать скрипт записывающий в файл уникальные ip и количество их посещений?

Tags: php

Вроде бы просто, но не хватает опыта. Скрипт записывающий уникальные ip - т.е($_SERVER('REMOTE_ADDR') и количество посещений в файл ip.txt.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А зачем? Эта информация есть в логах веб-сервера (у вас же есть логи веб-сервера?)

Comment: Задание в книге требует

Comment: @IvanSmagin Ну раз книга требует, то она и объясняет что делать до задания. Вывод: читайте книгу.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Запись IP-Адреса в переменную
$file = file('./ip.txt'); // Вместо ip.txt можно вписать другое расширение и название файла

if (in_array($ip, $file)) // Проверяем есть ли IP-Адрес в файле ip.txt и при отсутствии записываем
    echo 'Вы уже посещали эту страницу';
else
    file_put_contents('ip.txt', $ip, FILE_APPEND);
```

[Источник](https://www.cyberforum.ru/php-beginners/thread695635.html)